# VueJs Router: App.vue Component shows up on every page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frameworks, vue-router

I'm working with currently with the Vue Router, but when I write something in App.vue it shows up on every page, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `app.vue` will always render since it's the main component. To display a content specific to the page, you should use `<router-view />`. It will render the component you define on your route file. Here is the example

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import Login from '../views/Auth/Login.vue'
import Register from '../views/Auth/Register.vue'
import LandingPage from '../views/LandingPage.vue'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'LandingPage',
    component: LandingPage
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'Login',
    component: Login
  },
  {
    path: '/register',
    name: 'Register',
    component: Register
  },
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

export default router
```

Comment: Thank you! I just forgot to include the '/' path into index.js :)